# JavaFx Controller set Object Another Controller

Tags: java, javafx

I'am gettin Admin object in LoginController. Its not null there is no problem. When i setting this object AdminController its not working. In my initialize syso result showing "null".  I need to use this object in my other controller. Using swing i was doing this in controller constructors and swing construtors. But i dont know how i can do that with JavaFx. Sorry for my bad english. But if u look code, u will understand me.

```
    public class UserLoginController extends AbstractController {

    @FXML
    private Button joinBtn;
    @FXML
    private Button exitBtn;
    @FXML
    private Label statusLabel;
    @FXML
    private TextField userNo;
    @FXML
    private PasswordField password;


    @FXML
    void buttonEvent(ActionEvent event) {

        if (joinBtn == event.getSource()) {
            String userType = userNo.getText().substring(0, 2);
            switch (userType) {
            case "10":
                Admin admin = DBContext.getInstance().admins().isUserExist(Integer.parseInt(userNo.getText()), password.getText());
                if(admin != null) {
                    final String fxml = "/educationManagement/view/AdminPanel.fxml";
                    try {
                        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(fxml));
                        Parent root = (Parent) loader.load();
                        AdminController adminController = loader.getController();
                        adminController.setAdmin(admin);
                        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
                        Stage stage = (Stage) ((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
                        stage.setTitle(admin.getFirstName() + " " + admin.getLastName());
                        stage.setScene(scene);
                        stage.show();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        System.out.println("fuck");
                    }

                } else {
                    statusLabel.setText("Kullanıcı Adı veya Şifre Yanlış");
                    userNo.setText("");
                    password.setText("");
                }
                break;

            case "40":

                break;

            case "50":

                break;

            default:
                statusLabel.setText("Kullanıcı Adı Bulunamadı");
                break;
            }

        }
    }
}


public class AdminController implements Initializable{

    private Admin admin;

    @FXML
    private TableView<Student> studentTable;

    @FXML
    private Label firstNameLbl;

    public Admin getAdmin() {
        return admin;
    }

    public void setAdmin(Admin admin) {
        this.admin = admin;
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        System.out.println(admin);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The initialize method is being called when loading the FXML file, you should create another init method in AdminController that will do all the initialize that you need with the admin object, and call this method after the call to the setter:

```
 AdminController adminController = loader.getController();
 adminController.setAdmin(admin);
 adminController.initController();
```

Comment: Thank you so much Zoltanik. I create load method in Admin controller. I set admin then call load. Now i can show user information in components scene first showing.